# window.open and document.location stop window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i'm trying to use setTimeout() and window.open in the same script but i't doesn't seem to work.

code:

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_self'); setTimeout(function() { alert('bla')},4000);
```

or

> document.location='http://google.at'; setTimeout(function() { alert('bla') }, 4000);

why is that and how can i fix it?

edit: hey thanks for the anwsers, but why does this work then?

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');window.open('http://arstechnica.com', '_self'); alert('bla');
```

alert is shown and arstechnica is opened

Answer (score 0):

In both cases your code says:

1. Leave the current page and load a new one
2. After x seconds, show an alert

After you have left the page, the JavaScript execution environment for that page is destroyed. The script ends and there is no `alert` function to call.

Answer (score 0):

Once you navigate to Google (or any page for that matter), the browser loads new files and does not continue to run your script.

You could try opening Google in a new page, and then it will continue running your code in the old page .